# How to escape variable in a postgresql insert query into a python script?

Tags: python, postgresql

I have an issue with a Python script and i cannot find answers into the web, or i cannot implement them or they doesn't work for me :/

I have a Python script and into it i have an INSERT query for a Postgresql database.

This is the query :

```
        print('Insert Site')
        with conn.cursor() as cur:
            cur.execute(
                """ INSERT INTO `site_file` (`nameSite_File`, `ownerSite_File`, `typeSite`, `linkSite_File`, `lastVisite`, lastUpdate) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s); """,
                (site[0], site[1], site[2], site[3], site[4], site[5]))
            conn.commit()
            cur.close()
```

And this is the error :

```
--
[u"Decat'personnalisation", u'daft.punk@decathlon.com', 'New Album is Awesome', u'https://sites.google.com', NULL, '2017-07-13']
Unexpected Error
--
```

I'm really new on Python but i'm pretty sure it is because it doesn't escape the quote of the nameSite variable

Thanks a lot for your time & your help,

Thomas.

Comment: why are you using  triple quote( """ ) insted of double quote ( "" )?

Comment: It looks like you have a NULL variable in your site list, doesn't look normal

Comment: @MKPatel idon't know i am trying to fix someone else script :/ do you think it can help to user only double quote ?

Comment: @Manu Yes sometimes i can have a null variable, it does work with other record  so i think this is not the problem

Comment: okk then try it with double quote.. check the output..

Comment: Nothing at all wrong with the triple quotes and quite common with embedded SQL source because a statement may have to be spread over multiple lines to make it readable. PostgreSQL sees only a string, not how it was quoted in Python.

Comment: @ThomasMOREAU try to print site variable before using it

Comment: @ThomasMOREAU also your error looks small, maybe edit your question to post the full error

Answer (score 1):

PostgreSQL doesn't use backticks `` like mysql does. It uses [double quotes](https://github.com/yzh44yzh/erma/issues/5) `""` (which is much more standard SQL) instead. Which means that you need to retain the triple quotes around your SQL `insert` statement.